# Множественные подключения по BLE в Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Здравствуйте! Пишу приложение, в котором используется BLE и есть необходимость подключаться к нескольким устройствам, за основу был взят сэмпл с офф сайта, который переделываю под себя. Для подключения используется метод

```
mBluetoothLeServise.connect(mDeviceAdress);
```

далее соединение разрывается соединение методом

```
mBluetoothLeServise.close;
```

Все работает, НО если я работаю с одним и тем же устройством, то все ок, отклик минимальный, но если отправлять команды на азные устройства(сначала на одно, потом на другое), то возникает временная задержка(время на поиск и коннект, как я понимаю).

Вопрос: можно ли создать несколько объектов класса `BluetoothLeServise` для ускорения работы и как в этом случае пользоваться методом `onServiceConnected`?

Да, вопрос странный, но по какой то причине когда я пытался создать несколько объектов этого класса, он определялся только для 1 элемента.

И за одно спрошу, можно ли изменить стандартный таймаут подключения (стандартный вроде 5 сек).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upd...
Разобрался окончательно и теперь все выглядит так:
Для минимализации вериени переключения между устройствами при каждом новом подключении нужно заново подключаться через device.connectGatt(), т е gatt профиль должен обновляться при каждом новом подключении, но, процесс синхронизации сервисов (gatt.discoverServisies()), возможно, из за нехватки ресурсов, на слабых устройствах будет занимать  больше времени(2-3 сек у galaxy s3 против 100-300 миллисекунд у oneplus one), от этого никуда не деться. Да, и при отключении обязательно вызывать gatt.close(), а не gatt.disconnect(), во втором случае сохраненный gatt профиль устройства не сбросится и могут возниктуть проблемы со следующим подключением, этот метод(disconnect() следует использовать, только если вы хотите остановить процесс подключения к устройству до того как соединение установленно.
Но, если не обязательно разрывать соединение после каждого сеанса команд, то можно подключиться сразу к нескольким устройствам(в теории на api 19+ до 7 устройств).

Как то так.
PS: сорри, если предыдущим ответом ввёл кого либо в заблуждение. И все выше, это исключительно личный опыт, так что возможно что то обстоит по другому.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по исходникам, `BluetoothLeService` это потомок обычной службы Андроид, в этом случае нет, больше одного экземпляра не запустите.
И она изначально написана для общения только с одним устройством, Вы правы насчет задержек.
Выход: написать что-то свое на базе `BluetoothLeService`.